# Solve set of equations: $\frac{9}{x+y}+y=6$ and $\frac{x}{x+1} +\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{xy+x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve set of equations:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}
$\frac{9}{x+y}+y=6\\
\frac{x}{x+1} +\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{xy+x}\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I dont know how to deal with this problem: I've try to add, sub 2 equation.

I also try multiple the first equation with ($x+y$), the second ones with $x(x+1)y(y+1)$ but still stuck.

Comment: I doubt that these equations have a nice solution. I suggest solving the first for $x$ in terms of $y$ (the result will be quadratic in $y$), then substituting for $x$ in the second to get an ugly equation in $y$. Try to solve that one numerically (perhaps in Desmos?). If you [edit] the question to tell us where it comes from we might have other suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried solving the top equation for x in terms of y?  Then substituting?

Comment: This kind of system is normally solved by a method called “give up [and ask WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=9%2F%28x%2By%29%2By%3D6%2C+x%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B1%2Fy%3D1%2F%28xy%2Bx%29)”.  There are 2 real and 4 complex solution pairs.

Comment: Using $x$ in second equation gives $y^6-10\,y^5+31\,y^4-14\,y^3-57\,y^2-27\,y+135=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in need of visualization. I did choose Mathematica and function of two variables interpretation of the given equations independently.

[image: plot f(x,y) and g(x,y)]

The plot shows that there are not only points that are solutions. The honey-like-colored first equation shows the singularity at $x==y$ across the plot.

The solutions are rather complicated curves than easy points or lines. This whole lot of work is done without a restriction to the domain. I simply took reals.

It is clear that all the singularities are gone if the equations are turned into proper polynomials.

$9+(y-6)(x+y)=0$
$xy(xy+x)+(x+1)(xy+x)-(x+1)y=0$

The second equation can be simplified further to $x - y + x^2 (1 + y)^2=0$

The plot looks then

[image: plot of polynomials]

So working with non-singular polynomials simplifies the problem posed immensely.

Even if Mathematica does not use the complexes as domain canonically the results are represented as [Root](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html).

But try yourself of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B9%20%2B%20%28y%20-%206%29%20%28x%20%2B%20y%29%20%3D%3D%200%20%26%26%20%20%20%20x%20y%20%28x%20y%20%2B%20x%29%20%2B%20%28x%20%2B%201%29%20%28x%20y%20%2B%20x%29%20-%20%28x%20%2B%201%29%20y%20%3D%3D%200%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20y%7D%5D) for numbers:

[image: solution simplified]

But this solution does not look too convincing.

[image: Mathematica solutions]

That is really hard to be visualized.

So parameterized roots can have complicated branch cuts in the complex parameter plane!

This is only the generic approach to solutions. This is neither an solution paths that garantees completeness nor is it optimized for the high degree of [Root](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) nor is this the best solution to represent the solution set. It might be despite of that really close.

In $FullForm$ the results starts with

```
List[List[
  Rule[x, Root[
    Function[
     Plus[9, Times[-12, Slot[1]], Times[-94, Power[Slot[1], 2]], 
      Times[102, Power[Slot[1], 3]], Times[248, Power[Slot[1], 4]], 
      Times[-223, Power[Slot[1], 5]], Times[49, Power[Slot[1], 6]]]], 
    1, 0]], Rule[y, 
   Times[Rational[1, 1591], 
    Plus[22788, 
     Times[8665, 
      Root[Function[
        Plus[9, Times[-12, Slot[1]], Times[-94, Power[Slot[1], 2]], 
         Times[102, Power[Slot[1], 3]], Times[248, Power[Slot[1], 4]],
          Times[-223, Power[Slot[1], 5]], 
         Times[49, Power[Slot[1], 6]]]], 1, 0]], 
     Times[-123425, 
      Power[Root[
        Function[
         Plus[9, Times[-12, Slot[1]], Times[-94, Power[Slot[1], 2]], 
          Times[102, Power[Slot[1], 3]], 
          Times[248, Power[Slot[1], 4]], 
          Times[-223, Power[Slot[1], 5]], 
          Times[49, Power[Slot[1], 6]]]], 1, 0], 2]], 
     Times[-70154, 
      Power[Root[
        Function[
         Plus[9, Times[-12, Slot[1]], Times[-94, Power[Slot[1], 2]], 
          Times[102, Power[Slot[1], 3]], 
          Times[248, Power[Slot[1], 4]], 
          Times[-223, Power[Slot[1], 5]], 
          Times[49, Power[Slot[1], 6]]]], 1, 0], 3]], 
     Times[109129, 
      Power[Root[
        Function[
         Plus[9, Times[-12, Slot[1]], Times[-94, Power[Slot[1], 2]], 
          Times[102, Power[Slot[1], 3]], 
          Times[248, Power[Slot[1], 4]], 
          Times[-223, Power[Slot[1], 5]], 
          Times[49, Power[Slot[1], 6]]]], 1, 0], 4]], 
     Times[-27489, 
      Power[Root[
        Function[
         Plus[9, Times[-12, Slot[1]], Times[-94, Power[Slot[1], 2]], 
          Times[102, Power[Slot[1], 3]], 
          Times[248, Power[Slot[1], 4]], 
          Times[-223, Power[Slot[1], 5]], 
          Times[49, Power[Slot[1], 6]]]], 1, 0], 5]]]]]],...
```

So these are [Root](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) of degree six.

For better results restrict from `{x,y}` being both complexes.

Answer (score 0):

The equations as written already require $xy+x \neq 0 \ (\implies x \neq 0, y\neq -1), y \neq 0, x \neq 1, x \neq y$. We can assume those constraints when simplifying.

The two equations simplify to $x^2+xy-6x-6y+9=0, \ x^2y^2+2x^2y+x^2+x-y=0$.

Rather than going to W|A, I like going to Desmos, especially since we now have well-behaved(-ish) polynomials. The first equation is a hyperbola, though a tilted one. The second equation is multi-valued and, of course, is quartic rather than quadratic. I can't describe what it looks like. But [Desmos will graph them](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iuxx7ynhi5) and give you the two real solutions.

Finding a "proper" solution is beyond my pay grade on this one, and likely beyond that of many people here.